# How to add jars to java web netbeans project directory

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a java web project using Netbeans IDE. Now I want to add all Library files into the project directory. How can I solve it?

Comment: Right click in the project, properties, libraries..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click in the project, properties, libraries.

[image]